# Convert map of vectors to vectors of columns in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a collection (or list or sequence or vector) of maps like so:

```
{ :name "Bob", :data [32 11 180] }
{ :name "Joe", :data [ 4  8  30] }
{ :name "Sue", :data [10  9  40] }
```

I want to create new vectors containing the data in the vector "columns" associated with keys that describe the data, like so:

```
{ :ages [32 4 10], :shoe-sizes [11 8 9], :weights [180 30 40] }
```

Actually, a simple list of vectors might be adequate, i.e.:

```
[32 4 10] [11 8 9] [180 30 40]
```

If it's better/easier to make the original list into a vector, that's fine; whatever's simplest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

```
(def records
  [{:name "Bob" :data [32 11 180]}
   {:name "Joe" :data [ 4  8  30]}
   {:name "Sue" :data [10  9  40]}])
```

you could do next transformations to get the desired result:

```
(->> records
     (map :data) ; extract :data vectors 
     ; => ([32 11 180] [4 8 30] [10 9 40])
     (apply map vector) ; transpose
     ; => ([32 4 10] [11 8 9] [180 30 40])
     (zipmap [:ages :shoe-sizes :weights])) ; make map 
     ; => {:weights [180 30 40], :shoe-sizes [11 8 9], :ages [32 4 10]}
```

Without comments it looks a little bit cleaner:

```
(->> records 
     (map :data)
     (apply map vector)
     (zipmap [:ages :shoe-sizes :weights]))
```

Without [threading](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) macro it is equivalent to more verbose:

```
(let [extracted (map :data records)
      transposed (apply map vector extracted)
      result (zipmap [:ages :shoe-sizes :weights] transposed)]
  result)
```

Comment: This answer is quite good, but as the OP is a "clojure newbie", you may want to explain use of the treading macro `(->>)` and possibly add a version with intermediate `def` or `let`s.

Comment: Incredible! Thank you. Yes, an alternative using `let` would be helpful. Trying to wrap my mind around the thrush macro...

Comment: Without threading macro code looks almost identical - instead of passing result of transformation directly to the next step we introduce new intermediate binding. However I agree that this version (despite of being a bit more verbose) may be more readable. Now answer is updated.

Comment: OK, I still don't totally understand the difference between the two "thrush" macros `->` and `->>` (http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E), but using `macroexpand-all` helped. For example, without the zipmap part, it expands to `(apply map vector (map :data records))`.

Comment: Thanks for the `let` version. All very helpful.

Comment: @Mr.Fussyfont the difference between the threading macros is that `->` "thread first" inserts  each form as the **second** item (e.i., the first "argument") of  the following form, whereas '->>' "thread last" inserts as the **last** item. In this case, you want for instance the first form to be `(map :data records)`, so `->>` is the one to use. `(-> records (map :data))` would expand to `(map records :data)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use reduce like this:

```
(def data [{ :name "Bob", :data [32 11 180] }
           { :name "Joe", :data [ 4  8  30] }
           { :name "Sue", :data [10  9  40] }])

(reduce 
  (fn [acc {[age shoe-size weight] :data}]
    (-> acc
      (update-in [:ages] conj age)
      (update-in [:shoe-sizes] conj shoe-size)
      (update-in [:weights] conj weight)))
{}
data)
```

Returns something like this:

```
{:weights (40 30 180), :shoe-sizes (9 8 11), :ages (10 4 32)}
```

I think the most interesting part of this code is the use of nested destructuring to grab hold of the keys: `{[age shoe-size weight] :data}`

Comment: -.- I just finished my solution 2 minutes to late and it looks almost like yours. However, for me getting grips around reduce and how to use it was harder to get than understanding the destructuring.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thank you. I don't understand your solution yet, but I'll fool around with it and post an update or accept your answer.